# Nest Device Access not publishing to pub/sub

Tags: nest-device-access

All:

This topic has appeared before with no answers and for some reason been de-listed (not a valid question).  The Nest Device Access Console states to ask questions on this forum so I will try again:

I have followed all the steps to get a Nest Doorbell to publish events/messages to Google pub/sub (i.e. https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/get-started) and yet nothing is being pushed to the topic (i.e. flat line in pub/sub subscription window).  Is there something obvious I'm missing, not read, regarding support for the Nest doorbell and pub/sub?

In short, it would be nice if a Google representative/expert could weigh in on this topic and provide some insight.

Thanks,

Rob.

Comment: Very odd, the queue started to fill yesterday for some reason - no idea why.  Will monitor to see if it stays working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something on Google's part. At my home the doorbell is working again as well :-) So you probably didn't misread anything and were just part of some sort of glitch.